# Css calc() in js

Tags: javascript, css

I need to mix units in a dynamically generated div, but this doesn't render (ie left is still the default after that line is executed).

Any help appreciated.

```
 var tab3 = document.createElement('div');
 tab3.className = 'tab';
 tab3.style.display = 'none';
 tab2.style.left = 'calc(~"200px+40vw")px';
```

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and produce a [mcve]

Comment: Do you actually inject tab3 somewhere in your DOM ? What is tab2 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got several mistakes in your calc expression:

```
calc(~"200px+40vw")px` -> `calc(200px + 40vw)
```

1. According to [@JohnWeisz's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58622599/css-calc-in-js/58622702#comment103553439_58622702) - calc(~"200px+40vw")px is a Less expression, ~"..." is used to prevent Less from processing the addition operation from the source stylesheet files, but that's both invalid syntax and unnecessary from CSS string context.
2. [@G-Cyr adds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58622599/css-calc-in-js/58622702#comment103555017_58622702) that white space is required on both sides of the + and - operators. The * and / operators can be used without white space around them.

Example:

```js
 var tab3 = document.createElement('div');
 tab3.className = 'tab';
 tab3.style.left = 'calc(20px + 40vw)';
  
document.body.append(tab3);
```

```css
.tab {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vh;
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: Explanation: `calc(~"200px+40vw")px` is a Less expression, `~` is used to prevent Less from processing the addition operation from the source stylesheet files, but that's both invalid syntax and unnecessary from JS string context.

Comment: @JohnWeisz - I was adding my explanation to the answer, but I'll take your nice comment instead :)

Comment: also *In addition, white space is required on both sides of the + and - operators. (The * and / operators can be used without white space around them.)*  https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#calc-syntax would be worth to remind ... :)